# Keeping rootfs with Inheriting rm_work in yocto

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, rootfs

To save disk space, I have added `INHERIT += "rm_work"`

I don't want it to delete root file system folder, so I added the following line in local.conf.

```
RM_WORK_EXCLUDE += "rootfs"
```

I ran the following command to get the location of root file system

```
bitbake -e core-image-minimal | grep ^IMAGE_ROOTFS=
```

CD failed with directory not exist. What mistake I am doing here.

Thanks for your time

Comment: I think you need to put `RM_WORK_EXCLUDE += "core-image-minimal"` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RM_WORK_EXCLUDE += "rootfs" will check for any recipe named `rootfs` and exclude that from rm_work while building.

In your case rootfs is created using `core-image-minimal` recipe. So use

```
RM_WORK_EXCLUDE += " core-image_minimal".
```